# Merging different size multiple csv files

Tags: r, csv

Please help me to write a code in combining multiple csv files in R using a common field in all the files (but each file has diff no. of rows like 702, 666, etc.) and for missing values I need NA in the place of missing values.

For your easy understanding, here I am showing how an individual file looks since here I cannot attach multiple files. I am just pasting one. **name** is the common filed in all the files.  With the filename as its header along with its column name.

```
    name   projected_leaf_area  treatment  species      g_alias     replicates
1   A-2:1   215.209             WW       Chickpea  ICCRIL03-0013    2
2   A-2:2   148.404             WW       Chickpea  ICCRIL03-0119    2
3   A-2:3   206.566             WW        Chickpea ICCRIL03-0007    2
.  .. .  . .  ... ........  ......
 .  .. .  . .   ... ........  ...... 
702 B-2:234 242.06              WW        Chickpea ICCRIL03-0143    4
```

please help me to merge the files friends... thanks for your time...

Comment: Please, format your question properly. Upper-case text has a specific meaning on the internet, it means you're shouting ! So please don't use it just to highlight some sentences, use bold or italic text instead.

Comment: sorry  from next time onwards I ll not use it.. I thought just to highlight it but from onwards I will use bold or italics... thank u and sorry...

Comment: Please make your problem reproducible. Chatting in comments isn't the way to go.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Sir but how to make it public discussion??? for their answer it is the way how I m supposed to reply right??? or if there any other way I m happy to use that...

Comment: In my view, comments are for clarifying things that should not be in the main question. I think answers fail to provide  you with out of the box solutions is because your question is not clear enough. Please, do not  feel offended, consider my comment and act, or not, on it.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik thanks for your suggestions I ll act accordingly.. what is not clear about my question.. if you say I would be much pleased to change it.. already I have made few changes after listening to you.. thank you..

Comment: Provide enough data to demonstrate your problem and show us what the expected result should look like. If there are any borderline cases, point that out, too. To get you started, there are a few tips on how to go about [point one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Load all of the files using `read.csv` and `merge` them together using `Reduce`:

```
files <- dir(pattern = ".csv")
d <- lapply(files, read.csv, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
for(i in seq_along(d)) {
    names(d[[i]]) <- paste0(files[i], ".", names(d[[i]]))
}
Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x,y,by="name", all=TRUE, sort = FALSE), d)
```

Comment: thank you so much for your time Thomas... but it is combining all the csv files down by down (vertically).. I want to be combined horizontally with the common field. please?????

Comment: You'll have to elaborate. You probably want to use `merge` (or maybe `cbind`) instead of `rbind`, but it depends on exactly how you want to combine rows.

Comment: Thomas for different size rows cbind cannot be used right??? if I try to use merge , files <- dir(pattern = ".csv")
d <- lapply(files, read.csv, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
Q<-do.call("merge (files) by="name",all=TRUE, sort = F)", d)......

it is showing error as "Error: unexpected symbol in "Q<-do.call("merge (files) by="name" ".... see the above in the original question I have pasted you how exactly all my looks, so based on the name field I want all my csv files combined with its fila names as header... for example my file names would be s5, s6, s7, s8...

Comment: so in the combined output I would need, as s5.projected_leaf_area,  s5.treatment ,s5.species ,s5.g_alias, s5.replicates, s6.projected_leaf_area  s6.treatment  s6.species      s6.g_alias     s6.replicates and so on.. totally I have 50 files.. the column field name would be common in all the files.. 

hope now I explained u clearly.. 
looking forward your reply please...

Comment: when ever I run the last line(reduce) the following error is coming, Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column
Called from: stop(ngettext(sum(bad), "'by' must specify a uniquely valid column", 
    "'by' must specify uniquely valid columns"), domain = NA)
Browse[1]> 

the above error I m getting again while this new cose sorry... it is asking me to debug by "fix.by"..... how to solve this please...???

Answer (score 0):

```
file.data <- lapply(file.names, function(fn){read.csv(fn)})    
common.cols <- Reduce('intersect', lapply(file.data, colnames))
do.call('rbind', lapply(file.data, function(fd) fd[, common.cols]))
```

#

Ignore the above
Try

```
mergeall <- function(x, y){merge(x, y, all = TRUE)}
file.data <- lapply(file.names, function(fn){read.csv(fn)})
# example data:
# file.data[[1]] <- data.frame(id = letters[1:4], val1 = 1:4)
# file.data[[2]] <- data.frame(id = letters[1:3], val2 = c(1, NA, 2))
# file.data[[3]] <- data.frame(id = letters[2:5], val3 = factor(letters[1:4]))
Reduce('mergeall', file.data)
#   id val1 val2 val3
# 1  a    1    1 <NA>
# 2  b    2   NA    a
# 3  c    3    2    b
# 4  d    4   NA    c
# 5  e   NA   NA    d
```

Comment: thank you so much for your time Russ...  but it is showing an error of file.names not found??? please could you tell why???

Comment: you would need to define file.names <- c(...) as a string of file names you wish to import.

Comment: Natty could you please elaborate... sorry I couldn't get your point.. I m new to this r programming environment.. my file names would be like s6, s7, s8, s9, .....s50

Comment: It is similar to how @Thomas has defined them `files <- dir(pattern = ".csv")`

Comment: Russ, I m getting error in the source viewer as (lapply debugging),                                                                                    function (X, FUN, ...) 
{
    FUN <- match.fun(FUN)
    if (!is.vector(X) || is.object(X)) 
        X <- as.list(X)
    .Internal(lapply(X, FUN))
}                                                                                                                            if I try run this, I m getting error as---- Error during wrapup: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable... please could you tell me how to solve this????

Comment: @russ hyde -- but hyde can you please tell me how to use merge command in your code??? I cannot use cbind since I m not having same size data frames...

Comment: oh, disregard this post, it doesn't do what you need. Next time give us a reproducible testcase

Comment: I've edited the code to do what you apparently wanted. Thomas has already given you this solution though

Comment: @Russ Hyde thanks for your great help.. actually your code made me to succeed in combining all my csv files 98% perfectly :). thanks lot... but only problem is its not maintaining the order of the common field based on which the files has to be combined. in other words, my common field name in the file and the data in this column looks like A-2:1 A-2:2 A-2:3 A-2:4 A-2:5 .......... ......... A-2:232 A-2:233 A-2:234 B-1:1 B-1:2 B-1:3 B-1:4 B-1:5 B-1:6 B-1:7 B-1:8 ..... ........ B-1:229 B-1:230 B-1:231 B-1:232 B-1:233 B-1:234....sorryi ll cont in the next comment

Comment: so what I tried is sort = False.. its works to a certain extent.. but wherever I am getting missing values its going down the row separately... but I don't want like this... it has to maintain the same order like the common field... pls help me with this...also can you pls tell me how to get the file names in the header since I m having date in the names of 100 files , I need them to be on the header to identify which file is which????

Comment: @RussHyde--- is there is anyway to attach my csv file to this forum... so that it will be very clear to you what I am requesting you for????